# Unable to create a managed promise instance - if function written with async/await

Tags: typescript, promise, async-await, jasmine, protractor

Protractor fails with

> Unable to create a managed promise instance: the promise manager has
>   been disabled by the SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER environment variable:
>   undefined

If any function in test written in async/await way.
If function is written with promise chaines - everything works ok.

Below code will fail with above error:

```
it('Inner', async function () {
    await browser.get(this.getRootPath());
    await asyncF(); // Fails here
});

async function asyncF (): promise.Promise<boolean> {
    const loginButton: ElementFinder = element(by.id('login-btn'));
    const res = await loginButton.isDisplayed();
    return res;
}
```

Below code will work OK:

```
function asyncF (): promise.Promise<boolean> {
    const loginButton: ElementFinder = Utils.selectElementById('login-btn');
    return loginButton.isDisplayed();
}
```

I expect both code versions to work in same way

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem.
If using async/await syntax `asyncF ()` should return `Promise<T>`

For `return` case we actually return `promise.Promise<T>` and seems that's why it hasn't been working for the async/await.

Summing up:

```
async function asyncF (): Promise<boolean> {
    const loginButton: ElementFinder = Utils.selectElementById('login-btn');
    const res = await loginButton.isDisplayed();
    return res;
}
```

works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You could try resolving the promise in a different way using `async/await`

```
async function asyncF (): promise.Promise<boolean> {
    const loginButton: ElementFinder = Utils.selectElementById('login-btn');
    const res = await loginButton.isDisplayed();
    return res;
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing because op hasn't added a MCVE that they **also** need to await `Utils.selectElementById`

Comment: @Liam, sorry, needed to show that function too - it's implementation `element(by.id(selector))`